# How would I solve this question using the cosine rule?

Tags: trigonometry

[Question image](https://i.ibb.co/64fRXNd/Screenshot-from-2022-09-05-17-27-42.png)

I am stuck on this problem and have no idea how to go about solving it. I am supposed to be using the cosine rule:

$$
a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(A)
$$
$$
\cos(A)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}
$$

I can find $MD=\sqrt{136-120\cos(60+\arccos({\frac{18}{25}}))}$ but I don't know how to represent that as a surd. I think I have gone the wrong way in going about this and would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\cos(a+b)$?

Comment: CMD is a right-angled triangle, and you know $CD$ and $CM$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Is the bisector creating a right angle though? I didn't think it was. It can't be as $\angle{DCM}\approx113.13$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio No but I am supposed to be learning this material before starting my course at uni as I didn't take maths A-Level so maybe I need to know it too. It didn't come up during the "lesson" part of this problem set though

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ helped a lot got it to $MD=2\sqrt{25+12\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without explicitly calculating for you, here's a plan to attack the problem:

You can find both lengths just using the Pythagorean theorem, as each is the leg of a right triangle for which you are given the other leg and hypotenuse. (Notice that $|AM| = \tfrac12|AC| = \tfrac12 (12) = 6$.)

Now, the angle between the planes is actually the angle $\angle BMD$, and you have the lengths of all three sides of $\triangle BMD$, so you can use Al-Kashi's law of cosines in the second form that you wrote above to find the cosine of the angle. Finally, apply the inverse cosine to get the angle itself.

Comment: Are they definietly right triangles DMC and DMA? I was using triangle DBA being isoceles and the cosine rule to work out $\angle{DCB}=\angle{DBC}=\arccos(\frac{10^2+12^2-10^2}{2\cdot\cdot12\cdot10})$ and as triangle CBA is equilateral the angles are all 60 which makes $\angle{DCM}\approx60+53.13\approx113.13$ and therefore it cant be a right triangle. Maybe I have made a big mistake somewhere in my working though ahah

Comment: I totally missed CBA being isoceles so it must be a right angled triangle thanks for the guidance!